# Shrinking database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, shrink

I have shrink the large database. I have shrink the database log using SSMS and by query both way. on the properties it is showing the reduced size. But on the drive where it is mounted showing the previous size. What can I do to release the space after shrink of database?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't store every single byte separately - it allocates blocks of storage that it then manages itself. If you "free" some space up, SQL Server doesn't release that disk space back to the OS - and that's a **good thing!** It will later on reuse that space, without having to allocate it again from the OS (thus being able to use it more quickly)

Comment: Hi @marc_s, my doubt is that my Logdata folder and Log file size was 50 GB initially. after shrinking log the log file size is 1 MB , but folder size is showing 50 GB. is there is any way to use this space. I want to use the space because there is only less than 10 GB free space is available on hard disk. is this will create problem to application?

Comment: If you don't need log - change recovery model from `FULL` to `SIMPLE`. Shrink file with `SHRINKFILE` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493(v=sql.120).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

After you shrink database and see the database size is reduced to release the unused empty space to file system, you can execute DBCC SHRINKDATABASE command with TRUNCATEONLY option once more